# Take() in Directory.EnumerateFiles or Directory.GetFiles

Tags: c#, .net, foreach, parallel.foreach

Use .take() in Directory.EnumerateFiles or Directory.GetFiles is allowed??

I have this and works

```
    Parallel.ForEach(Directory.EnumerateFiles(sourceFolder, "*", 
               SearchOption.AllDirectories), file =>
    {
         //DO SOMETHING

    });
```

I want to  do the cycle only in as example 100 files. So:

```
    Parallel.ForEach(Directory.EnumerateFiles(sourceFolder, "*",
              SearchOption.AllDirectories).Take(100), file =>
    {
         //DO SOMETHING

    });
```

But the cycle is not recorred 100 time as I expected.

Why?

Comment: Are you sure there are at least 100 files in the source folder?

Comment: how many times is it running, and how are you measuring how many times it's running?

Comment: Yes I was trying with .Take(2) and I had like 20 files.

Comment: What is the results besides not as expected?

Comment: My fault. This is working well. I was trying to somehting with files of the root of the disk, but this is starting with hidden files of the Recycle Bin. Thats why I did not see anything. The cycle works as expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's absolutely fine to do that. It will limit the results to the first 100 files returned by `EnumerateFiles`. It will *not* execute the block 100 times if there aren't 100 files though... it's just a limiting factor.